# Is it advisable to use the Windows API 'SetThreadPriority' within a parallel_for_each loop

Tags: windows, winapi, parallel-processing, thread-priority

I would like to reduce the thread-priority of the threads servicing a parallel_for_each, because under heavy load conditions they consume too much processor time relative to other threads in my system.

Questions:

1) Do the servicing threads of a parallel_for_each inherit the thread-priority of the calling thread?  In this case I could presumably call SetThreadPriority before and after the parallel_for_each, and everything should be fine.

2) Alternatively is it advisable to call SetThreadPriority within the parallel_for_each?  This will clearly invoke the API multiple times for the same threads.  Is there a large overhead of doing this?

2.b) Assuming that I do this, will it affect thread-priorities the next time that parallel_for_each is called - ie do I need to somehow reset the priority of each thread afterwards?

3) I'm wondering about thread-priorities in general.  Would anyone like to comment: supposing that I had 2 threads contending for a single processor and one was set to "below-normal" while the other was "normal" priority.  Roughly what percentage more processor time would the one thread get compared to the other?

Comment: Pretty sure that SetThreadPriority isn't going to solve your problem.  You'll need to tinker with the SchedulerPolicy class, PolicyElementKey::ContextPriority to control the priority of the worker threads.

Comment: @Hans Surely reducing the number of threads, rather than reducing priority, is what's needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All threads initially start at `THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL`. So you'd have to reduce the priority of each thread. Or reduce the priority of the owning process.
2. There is little overhead in calling `SetThreadPriority`. Once you have woken up a thread, the additional cost of calling `SetThreadPriority` is negligible. Once you set the thread's priority it will remain at that value until changed.
3. Suppose that you have one processor, and two threads ready to run. The scheduler will always choose to run the thread with the higher priority. This means that in your scenario, the below normal threads would never run. In reality, there's a lot more to scheduling than that. For example priority inversion. However, you can think of it like this. If all processors are busy with normal priority threads, then expect lower priority threads to be starved of CPU.

Comment: Thanks @David - that's very helpful.

Just one last thing.  If I understand your answer 1 correctly, then the next time I call parallel_for_each, all servicing threads will revert back to THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL regardless of what I've done to them previously.

Alternatively from your answer to 2 I could glean that the thread-priority of threads servicing parallel_for_each would remain at the priority that I've previously given them.  In this case, I presume that the thing to do would be to perform another parallel_for_each in order to set the priorities back.

Any comments?

Comment: Well, I don't know how `parallel_for_each` is implemented, but I think Hans comment steers you in the right direction. Using `SetThreadPriority` is surely the wrong way to control priority. Also, changing priority will just result in your threads not running at all. I suspect you should simply use fewer threads.

Comment: I'll take a glance at PolicyElementKey::ContextPriority.
The problem is that under low-load conditions it is desirable to use a lot of threads for this operation, but under high-load fewer threads would be better.  Using thread-priority would be a simple solution that avoids having to implement a full load-balancing system.

Comment: So long as you don't mind your threads never running when the machine is under high load.

Comment: Thanks @David - your advice is very helpful and has certainly given me some stuff to think about.